# React Route dynamic urls with undetermined slashes

Tags: reactjs, routes

I have an array of object I'm looping it and displaying in component 1 with links to `url-key`:

```
[
{"id":1, "url-key":"hello/how/are/you"},
{"id":2, "url-key":"another/url"},
{"id":3, "url-key":"yet/another/url"}
]
```

in component 2:

```
const UserPage = ({ match, location }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <p>
         hello user page.
      </p>  
    </>
  );
};
```

I've found that if use in Router:

```
<Route exact path="/user/:url_key+" component={component2} />
```

the above router is fine except that can load anything after /user/blabla and it will display:
`hello user page.` how can I match wiht the url in the array of objects ?

Thnkx

Comment: Is the `url-key` unique in array?

Comment: @Prathap Reddy  Yes. not single on is the same only the length some may contain more or less slashes

Comment: Added my answer. Let me know if that's not what you are looking for. And  please confirm if you need `/user` prefix in all your URL paths?

Answer (score 1):

You can do `.map` of the array as below in your `component 1` to map all the array `url-key` values to `component 2`

```js
<Routes>
  myArray.map(obj => <Route key={obj.id} exact path={obj["url-key"]} component={component2} />)
</Routes>
```

Comment: However it didn't quite work for me but the example put me in the right path. I'll place my answer to show how it worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Prathap Reddy  answer didn't quite work for me but definitely helpful:

This is what worked for me:

```
...
<Router>
{myArray.map(obj=> {return (<Route key={obj.id} exact path={"/"+obj.url_key} component={component2} />)})}
<Router>
...
```

I had to add prop `Key` to Route as it was complaining ERROR: `Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop. map` even thought all ID's are unique I've seen this happened in all `array.maps` in react.

Comment: Hey it's may bad. The `key` prop help react to identify the changes. Since we usually do add `key`, I have overlooked it. Though you have all unique ids in the object you still need to pass `key` prop. Check out more details on `key` prop significance [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html). Thanks for the update BTW 

Comment: @PrathapReddy no worries thanks for the info. by the way there is a spelling mistake in your answer `<Roures>`  it should be `<Router>` 

Comment: Corrected the typos. `"/"+obj.url_key` this has worked for you because you have given path starting from `root` ('/'), if you have `url-key` start from root then you can get it like `obj["url-key"]` as posted in my answer. Anyways, good that you solved. Congratulations  